# searchable drop down list with each options are like table rows

Tags: jquery, html

I want to create a dropdown list with each options are like table rows (it should looks like the following image). I don't interested in creating my own control, because it takes lot of time.

[image]

Any idea guys ?  Please give me some links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content that you want to display is very specific and I doubt that you'll find a plugin to do exactly what you're trying to achieve. Why not slide open a table from a searchable text box. I know its what you're trying to avoid, but it might end up being the most simple solution.

Look at this fiddle that i've created that makes use of a jQuery Searchable plugin.

http://jsfiddle.net/79psrru8/1/

html:

```
<div class="custom-dropdown">
    <input type="search" id="search" value="" class="dropdown-search" placeholder="Search">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
        <table class="dropdown-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4"> <span class="search-result-counter"></span>

                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <!-- table content here -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="//rawgithub.com/stidges/jquery-searchable/master/dist/jquery.searchable-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
```

css:

```
.custom-dropdown {
    position:relative;
}
.custom-dropdown .table-wrapper {
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:21px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    display:none;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.custom-dropdown .dropdown-table {
    width: 300px;
}
.custom-dropdown .dropdown-table td {
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('.dropdown-table').searchable({
        striped: true,
        searchType: 'fuzzy'
    });

    $(".dropdown-search").bind("keyup", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $table = $this.next();
        if ($this.val().length > 0 && $table.is(":hidden")) {
            $table.show();
        } else {
            $table.hide();
        }

        var resultCount = ($table.find("tr:visible").length - 1);
        $table.find(".search-result-counter").html(resultCount + " records found.");
    });
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: you almost done it, can you please make it exactly how it looks in my question ?

Comment: I'll leave the styling up to you :). With the example provided you can add as many rows and cells as you like and add any html element into the cells. You can also style the table as you see fit. So you should be all good. Please mark as answer if this helped.